# How to remove react-native-firebase from iOS while keeping it in Android?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I'm using https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/ for my react native project.
I want to use it only for Android and not for iOS. But Xcode fails to build saying it needs the firebase inside the PODS.

What should I do? 
Is there any file I should remove/update?

Comment: Do manual linking.

Comment: How? Any links?

Comment: Thanks, @SanyamJain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the commands I used to unlink the npm modules from iOS and keep them in Android:

```
react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler --platforms ios
react-native unlink react-native-reanimated --platforms ios
react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons --platforms ios
```